# Congruence system doesn't hold, though it should?

Tags: proof-verification, congruences

Determine all the $a \in \mathbb Z$ such the equation system is compatible in $\mathbb Z$

$$\begin{cases} 
6x \equiv a^{121} \pmod {20} \\ 
14x \equiv 3 \pmod {15}
\end{cases}$$

So, piece of cake, I just use the Chinese remainder theorem:

$$ \begin{cases}
6x \equiv a^{121} \pmod 4 \\ 
6x \equiv a^{121} \pmod 5
\end{cases}$$

$$\begin{cases} 14x \equiv 3 \pmod 5 \\
14x \equiv 3 \pmod 3
\end{cases}$$

By the CRT, the system will have an assured solution if

$$ \begin{cases} 14x \equiv 3 \pmod 5  \\
6x \equiv a^{121} \pmod 5
\end{cases}$$

is consistent. Using some basic properties and the fermat theorem, I finally get:

$$a \equiv 2 \pmod 5$$

So for any given $a$ the the system should work, shouldn’t it?

BUT if I take $a = 7$, it assures the condition, but $6x \equiv a^{121}\equiv3 \pmod 4$ will be impossible to solve.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: One needs to pay attention to the mod $4$ part.

Comment: But $7^{121} \equiv 7 \pmod{20}$, not $3$.

Comment: I continue using the CRT, $\begin{cases} 6x \equiv a^{121} \mod 4 \\ 6x \equiv a^{121} \mod 5 \end{cases}$ should verify

Comment: Anyway, $14x\equiv 3\pmod{15}$ immediately gives $x\equiv 12\pmod {15}$ so that we can take a few shortcuts.

Comment: oh, the $3$ es a $4$ sorry

Comment: $$a^{121}=\left(a^8\right)^{15}\cdot a=a\pmod {20}\;\;\text{(Why? Observe that}\;\;\varphi(20)=8\;\ldots)$$

Comment: What 3 is a 4??

Comment: @DonAntonio I already eddited. I messed up at the end of the reasoning